# 1つのJSファイルから、2つ以上のAjax（別url=PHP）を指定した動作は可能ですか？

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

PHP（Ajax）の連携を達成したいのですが、後方のPHPまで動作が連携されているのか否か、そもそも標題の仕様は技術的に無理なのかをご教示頂きたくお問い合わせさせて頂きました。

現在までに、親画面のイメージボタン押下で子画面を開き、当該子画面上のリストボックスで選択される品名コードを、親画面のテキスト枠へ戻す（貼り付ける）ことまで達成できています。

取り組んでいる課題は、親画面に戻ったテキスト枠右隣のラベルへ、品名名称を表示する別PHP動作への連携＝ここまでを一連とした作りにすることです。

子画面JSには品名コード一覧のリストボックスを生成するためのAjax（PHP呼び出し）が定義済みですが、品名名称を取得するため、更に別PHPの活用が必要と捉え、もう一つAjaxを定義した作りになっています。
（今回の問い合わせのタイトルの由来）

【質問】

## 1.以下の作りでalert("⇒②" + cd)が現れない理由は何が考えられるか？

既に一つ目のAjaxでPHPを開いたのに、別のAjaxからPHP（二つ目）を呼び出すことは可能なのか？
（下のJS末端部分の記載にあるとおり、当該子画面を閉じることができているので、末端まではなんとかたどり着いているように思われる。それだけに二つ目Ajaxが正常に呼べているのか否かが気になっています）

## 2.Ajaxで呼ばれるPHPまで無事処理が遷移しているのか否かを知る術を教えてください。

（今回示している原始的なAlert以外にあるのか）
利用ブラウザIE(ver11)の開発ツールで、子画面JSのデバッガを開いておくと（使い方よく分かってない）alert("⇒①" + cd); の後の.Ajax部分で、ステップが待機されている感じにみえます（グリーンの矢印）。F5の続行ボタンを押下すると、当該JSが閉じられてしまい、遷移先のPHPの状況など一切窺いしることができません。

```
$(function(){

    //曖昧検索テキストボックスに変化が生じたら
    $("[name=car_maker2]").on("change", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "cdselect.php",    //***一つ目　ＰＨＰ呼び出し***
        })
        .done(function(data){
            //当該子画面の品名コード検索用リストボックス生成
        })
    });


    //当該子画面の品名分類リストボックスに変化が生じたら・またはフォーカス外れたら．
    $("[name=car_maker]").on("change blur", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "cdselect.php",    //***上記同様一つ目　ＰＨＰ呼び出し***
        })
        .done(function(data){
            //当該子画面の品名コード検索用リストボックス生成
        })
    });



    //上記生成の品名コードのリストボックスで指定を受けたら=【子画面の本来の存在意義】
    $("[name=car_model]").on("change", function(){

        //親画面コード枠（TEXT）に選択リストボックスの値を戻す
        var cd = $(".car_model option:selected").val();

        //*****************************************************
        alert("⇒①" + cd);       //★★★表示された★★★
        $.ajax({            //***二つ目　ＰＨＰ呼び出し***
            url: "cdinfoget.php",
            data: {
                maker_no: cd    // 取得品名コードを名称取得PHPに渡す
            }
        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert("⇒②" + cd);   //★★★表示され『ない』★★★
        })
        //***************************************************************


        //親画面の品名コード枠へ取得した品名コードを格納 ⇒【達成されます】
        window.opener.$("#99").focus().val(cd);

        //当該子画面を閉じる ⇒【達成されます】
        close();
    });

});
```

以上です、よろしくお願い致します。

【コメントに対する画像】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「親画面の他項目表示用のphp」とありますが、具体的にはどのような項目ですか？「親画面表示項目補い」もよくわからないです。

Comment: 尋ねたい意欲は伝わりますが、回答者に何を答えて欲しいのかまったく伝わりません。「解決策があるのか、教えて下さい」と言われても「開発者を雇ってみては？」ぐらい返せなく、全くプログラミングの話題ではありません。[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html)などを参照し、何を答えて欲しいのかを明確にしてください。

Comment: 本文を全面的に改めます。すみません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .done(function(data){
        alert("⇒②" + cd);   //★★★表示され『ない』★★★
    })
    //***************************************************************


    //親画面の品名コード枠へ取得した品名コードを格納 ⇒【達成されます】
    window.opener.$("#99").focus().val(cd);

    //当該子画面を閉じる ⇒【達成されます】
    close();
```

の部分を

```
    .done(function(data){
        alert("⇒②" + cd);   //★★★表示され『ない』★★★

        //親画面の品名コード枠へ取得した品名コードを格納 ⇒【達成されます】
        window.opener.$("#99").focus().val(cd);

        //当該子画面を閉じる ⇒【達成されます】
        close();
    })
    //***************************************************************
```

に変更してみてください。
ajaxは非同期の処理になりますので、通信が完了してdone()が実行される前にclose()が実行されてしまい、画面が閉じてしまってalertが出ていないのだと思われます。

php側には問題なくリクエストは言ってると思います。

Comment: user17014様　完璧です！的確な指摘でした。本当にありがとうございました

Answer (score 2):

1の回答.
　ひとまずfailを追加しfail側が呼ばれるのであれば、何らかの理由で失敗しています。

2の回答
　開発ツールのネットワークタブを選択し、左上の緑の三角ボタンを押してください。
　その後通信を行うと、リクエスト、レスポンス等が見れるのでに通信に問題ないか確認してください

開発者ツールにはデバッグに有用なツールが入っていますので、一通り何ができるか把握する事をお勧めします。

Comment: hiro様　ご見解ありがとうございます。非常識なことをしているのではないか？と不安を抱いていましたが、達成できないこともなさそうな雰囲気に取れ、安心しました。
また開発ツールの有用な使い方をご紹介頂けたことで、解決に向け一歩前進した気がします。

実は問題のAjax部分には予め.failのコーディングは済ませていました。
.fail(function(){
   alert("2つ目のAjax！！！");
   console.log("失敗！！");
   window.opener.$(".errcd").html("err#004"); 
});
ところがメッセージボックスは現れない、子画面が閉じてしまい当該画面の開発ツールでコンソールを確認できないで困り果てていました。

ご教示頂きました開発ツール上のネットワークメニュ内での確認ですが、
親画面から開発ツールを立ち上げておくと以下の結果を得ました。

①当該子画面のＪＳの中で、品名名称を取得するために呼ばれるphpが、要約の部分で現れていた！
②詳細に切り替えて、応答本文タブを確認すると、求めたい情報（OracleからのSELECT結果）が文字化けしてるも行として現れていた！！

これは間違いなく、当該JSから二つ目のPHP（Ajax）が動作していると言って良いのですよね？？？