# 送信前に検知するエラー(独自のエラーコードの格納先)は、どこに保管すべき？

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

【質問】
クライアント側で設定でき、サーバ側でもクライアント側でも認識できる情報の保管先、かつ改ざんの可能性が低い達成方法をご教示ください。

・ページ間でその情報を共有する必要はございません。

－質問の背景－
画面内容がクライアント側（DBとの比較Ajax含む）で一通り精査された上、問題のない状況と判断された画面のみがサーバ向けに渡ってくる（SUBMITボタンが押下される）動作を達成したいと考えています。

これらけん制結果を、独自に設けるエラーコードとして『どこかに保存できないか』と思い　問い合わせさせて頂いております。

『保存の用途』
①SUBMITボタンを、エラーが一切ない状況の時のみ = 確保されたエラーコードが一切ない状況の時のみ
画面へ表示させたい。

②サーバ側にリクエストが渡ってきても、一応にエラーコードが一切存在していない状態を確認した上で処理を進行させたい。

－最後に－
こういたケースでは、INPUT TYPE="hidden"の項目を用い、サーバ側と情報共有することも　強ち間違いではないのかな？と思いましたが
けん制結果のエラーコードが、他人から書き換えられたら、一生サーバ側にリクエストが渡ってこない、と、ゾッとしてしまい、危険性を探る意味で問い合わせさせて頂きました。

不快な思いをされた方、非常に申し訳ありませんでした。引き続き、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 日本語初心者でしょうか、何を尋ねているのかさっぱりわかりません。例えば「エラーコード」がどこで生成された何のエラーを表す値なのかから第三者にはわかりません。やはり「開発者を雇ってみては？」が妥当な回答に思います。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/38962/4236 で質問を推敲した結果、全く別の質問になったことを学ばなかったのでしょうか。

Comment: sayuri様　昨日に引き続き申し訳ないです、本文を今改めます、ご容赦ください。

Comment: けん制結果とは、検証結果のことでしょうか。謝る必要はなくて、その業界で通じる用語を適切に選ぶ努力が必要と思います。あと、クライアントサイドの検証はあくまで補助とし、サーバーサイドで同等かそれ以上に厳しい検証を行う必要があります。

Comment: htb様 ご親切なご見解をありがとうございました。user17014様のご見解とあわせ、ようやくサーバ側でもけん制が必須であることを認識できました。重ねて御礼申し上げます
。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ここで言われているエラーは、エンドユーザーによるデータ入力時のエラーであることを前提としてお話しします。
私個人の考え方で申し訳ないですが、「エラーの詳細についてはどこにも保存しておく必要がない」が回答です。

エラーの詳細をどこかに保存し、保存されているエラーが存在しなければSubmit、および保存できるようにしたいという風にお見受けします。
しかし、このフローがそもそも誤りで、エラーチェックはSubmitの直前とデータ保存の直前の両方で全項目に対してその都度行い、その際にエラーがあればSubmit、または保存を中止し、ユーザーに入力内容の修正を促すべきです。
その際はユーザーにエラーメッセージを適切に提示してあげます。

もちろん、クライアントサイドの項目に対するblurイベントのたびに、その項目1件をチェックすることはUX上望ましいものです。
しかし、クライアントサイド側はいくらでも改ざんが可能で、その気になれば全く別のドメイン上のページからデータをPOSTする、なんてことも可能です。
このことからも最も重要なのはデータが送信され、受け取ってからのサーバーサイド上でのデータの整合性チェックということになります。(コメントでhtbさまが言われているのはこのことだと思います。)

個人的な考え方にのっとった回答のため、不適切であれば削除いたします。

Comment: ご丁寧なご回答をありがとうございました。

>という風にお見受けします。

全くそのとおりの意図で問い合わせておりました。恥ずかしながら．．．

htb様から早々にご見解を頂きましたが、実は自分の未熟さから
なぜサーバ側でも同等以上のチェックを図らなければならないのか理解に苦しんでおりました。

しかしuser17014様の以下ご見解で、少々（すみません分かりが悪く）その必要性を理解できた気がします。


>クライアントサイド側はいくらでも改ざんが可能で、
>その気になれば全く別のドメイン上のページからデータをPOSTする、なんてことも可能です。

クライアントの画面上の情報、また表示されていない情報にせよ、意図せず改ざんされる可能性がある。
このリスクを帯びたデータがサーバに渡ってくる可能性がある以上は
クライアント側のけん制だけに頼ることは危険、そういうことですね？？
（セッション情報に検証結果を保管できたとしても、
その検証結果を生み出した画面状態が渡ってくるとも限らない）


htb様のご見解を、注文を行うような画面で、常にサーバ上のデータが変化するシステムでの話し
（在庫を仮引当て=唾付けする必要のあるシステム）でのこと？？
と勝手な解釈をするほど、私は間違っていました。

Comment: @user17014 投稿が個人的に正しいと思われるならば、たとえそれが結果として実は不正確であったり間違っていたり主観的回答であったとしても、削除する必要はまったくないです。投稿をためらう必要もありませんし、むしろ推奨です。それが他人にとって有用だったかどうだったかの指標としての +1/-1 の投票です。（マイナス投票が重なってしまった場合には、自主的に削除したくなることはあるかもしれませんが。。）